# Android problem with release build (minify, debuggable)

Tags: android

I'm currently having problems with an error that only occurs in the release version of the app.
Some fields of the API request are empty. But this only occurs if the build has minify enabled and isn't debuggable. If I set debuggable to true or minify to false, it works.

So it must have something to do with the internal optimization of the app on releases. But i haven't looked into the process of minify and shrinking yet.

Does anyone have any tips on how to go about this type of error?

Comment: well you are activating proguards so please add proguards rules for ok http gson retrofit after adding it I hope it works for you

Answer (score 2):

If using retrofit, You will facing error when minify set become true, for solve that you must add code below in proguard file to keep retrofit class from obfuscated

```
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
```

And do that to your model data too

```
-keep class com.providoindodigital.mgoal.api.dao.news.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

After identifying the responsible model class, only adding `@Keep` helped. No proguard entry I tried made it working.